Springboot Entity Relationship
I've been searching for the official documentation on entity relationships in Spring Boot, such as @ManyToOne, @ManyToMany, etc., but I haven't found it yet. I've only come across posts from unofficial sources. Could someone point me to the official documentation?
Thanks in advance!

Because those annotations like @ManyToOne,@ManyToMany,etc.. are belong to javax.persistence lib which is part of Java EE.
You can also find these examples in spring boot github.

Actually there is an official documentation but it just dont provide specific examples of associations in a real project scenarios . I do recomand reading it since there is many methods to associate an Object to an other.
source : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/2.4.18/reference/html/
(chaptir 7 Section 7.6)
In the Other hand i do recomand sharing code so we can help you with your architecture.
